# SED: multiple patterns on the same line, how to match/parse first one

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file, which holds phone number data, and also some useless stuff.
I'm trying to parse the numbers out, and when there is only 1 phone number / line, it's not problem.
But when I have multiple numbers, sed matches the last one (even though everywhere it says it should match only match the first pattern?), and I can't get other numbers out..

My data.txt:

```
bla bla bla NUM:09011111111 bla bla bla bla NUM:08022222222 bla bla bla
```

When I parse for the data, my idea was first to remove all the "initial" "bla bla bla" in front of the first phone number (so I search for first occurrence of 'NUM:'), then I remove all the stuff after phone number, and get the number. 
After that I want to parse the next occurrence from the leftover string.

So now when I try to sed it, I always get the last number on the line:

```
>sed 's/.*NUM://' data.txt
08022222222 bla bla bla
>
```

Primarily I would like to understand what's wrong with my understanding of SED. Of course more efficient suggestions are welcome!
Doesn't my sed command say, replace all stuff before 'NUM:' with '' (empty)? Why it matches always the last occurrence ?

Thanks!

Comment: Sed is greedy. If there is a second NUM:, the first can be consumed by `.*` .

Comment: +1 for sample data, implied expected output AND some sample code that's not working. Good luck.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
echo "bla bla bla NUM:09011111111 bla bla bla bla NUM:08022222222 bla bla bla" |
sed 's/NUM:/\n&/g;s/[^\n]*\n\(NUM:[0-9]*\)[^\n]*/\1 /g;s/.$//'
NUM:09011111111 NUM:08022222222
```

The problem you have is understanding that the `.*` is greedy i.e. it matches the longest match *not* the first match. By placing a unique character (`\n` sed uses it as a line delimiter so it cannot exist in the line) in front of the string we're interested in (`NUM:...`)  and deleting everything that is not that unique character `[^\n]*` followed by the unique character `\n`, we effectively split the string into manageable pieces.

Comment: I was suspecting this was something to do with greediness indeed.

Comment: Wow that answers my hours-long search for an example of character-based as opposed to line-based sed work.  I see we stick the newline character as a marker in the line-based pattern space, then remove parts that end with that marker to counter sed's greedy match.

Comment: OSX: The '\n' doesn't work for sed. Use 'gsed' (installable with Brew) instead.

Answer (score 12):

As you know by now, `sed` regexes are greedy and as far as I can tell can't be made non-greedy.

Two alternatives that haven't been brought up until now are to just use other tools for this kind of matching/extraction.

You can use `perl` as a drop-in replacement for sed with the `-pe` parameters. It supports the `?` non-greedy modifier:

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*?NUM://' data.txt
09011111111 bla bla bla bla NUM:08022222222 bla bla bla
```

You can use the `-o` option to GNU grep to get only the bits of your data that match the regex:

```
$ egrep -o 'NUM:[0-9]*' data.txt 
NUM:09011111111
NUM:08022222222
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting an alternative, I will definitely look into the possible performance differences between sed and perl

Comment: Thanks for the egrep suggestion.  Too bad sed limits itself to pattern spaces taking entire lines.

Answer (score 3):

If a number is defined by digits following a `NUM:`:

```
sed -n -e 's/$/\n/' -e ':begin' \
  -e 's/\(NUM:[0-9][0-9]*\)\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\3 \1/' \
  -e 'tbegin' -e 's/.*\n //' -e '/NUM/p'
```

What this does is:

1. Put a `\n` at the end of the line to act as a marker.
2. Try to find a number before the marker, and put it at the end of the line (after the marker).
3. If a number was found, goto 2 above.
4. When no number are left before the marker, remove everything before the numbers.
5. If a number is on the line, print it (to handle the case where no number are found.

It can also be done the other way around, first dropping lines without numbers:

```
sed  -e '/NUM/!d' -e 's/$/\n/' -e ':begin' \
  -e 's/\(NUM:[0-9][0-9]*\)\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\3 \1/' \
  -e 'tbegin' -e 's/.*\n //'
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking time to give me an alternative solution, I will study it. 
However, it seems a bit difficult to understand though, and also there are quite many calls to sed here, I worry that performance is slower than in a "3-call solution"

Comment: There is a single call to `sed`, only a little more complex script with 6 commands.  You are right, potong's solution only have 3 commands, but those commands are executed more than once (the `g` argument to the `s` command), so it does not mean that it is faster.  I agree that it is a little more elegant for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*NUM:)(.*NUM:.*)$/\2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's/(-y)|(-f)|(\+incdir\+)/\n&/g' abcfile > cdeop
```

where abcfile would have as an example -y / -f / +incdir+ patterns , when patterns are matched it will insert new line before it.