# using sed for extracting multiple matches

Tags: sed

I have the following line:

```
echo AS:i:0  UQ:i:0  ZZ:Z:mus.sup  NM:i:0  MD:Z:50  ZZ:Z:cas.sup  CO:Z:endOfLine|sed 's/.*\(ZZ:Z:.*[ ]\).*/\1/g'
```

which outputs:

```
ZZ:Z:cas.sup
```

I'd like to use sed for extracting both `ZZ:Z` entries from the given line, such as (please avoid awk since the position of `ZZ:Z` entries may differ per each line in my file):

preferable output:

```
ZZ:Z:mus.sup  ZZ:Z:cas.sup
```

Or possibly:

```
ZZ:Z:mus.sup  
ZZ:Z:cas.sup
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `grep` with the `-o` (or `--only-matching`) flag:

```
$ grep -o 'ZZ:Z:[^ ]* ' <<< "AS:i:0  UQ:i:0  ZZ:Z:mus.sup  NM:i:0  MD:Z:50  ZZ:Z:cas.sup  CO:Z:endOfLine"
ZZ:Z:mus.sup 
ZZ:Z:cas.sup
```

Or with `sed`, based on this [@potong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9681880/1344961):

```
sed 's/ZZ:Z:/\n&/g;s/[^\n]*\n\(ZZ:Z:[^ ]* \)[^\n]*/\1 /g;s/.$//'
```

If you have only two occurrences of the pattern per line:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(ZZ:Z[^ ]*\).*\(ZZ:Z[^ ]*\).*/\1 \2/p' <<< "AS:i:0  UQ:i:0  ZZ:Z:mus.sup  NM:i:0  MD:Z:50  ZZ:Z:cas.sup  CO:Z:endOfLine"
```

Comment: #Kenavoz:
1. the sed solution doesn't work for me (at least not on Mac's terminal..)
2. Is there a way to make the [ grep -o ] solution to output per each line the two outputs in the SAME line? such as: 
ZZ:Z:mus.sup ZZ:Z:cas.sup 

Please refrain the solution of piping to 'tr' - such as:
grep -o 'ZZ:Z:[^ ]*'|tr '\n' ' ' 
because this solution outputs in one line ALL the ZZ:Z matches from a multiple lines file. 
The desired solution would be:  
pairs of ZZ:Z matches - such as: ZZ:Z:mus.sup ZZ:Z:cas.sup  in each line.
Thus collecting all ZZ:Z:  from each line and presenting in one line

Answer (score 1):

You can surely achieve it with `sed`, but wouldn't a  `tr` and `grep` solution be more natural (because you seem to actually have different logical records despite the fact they appear on a single line):

```
echo AS:i:0  UQ:i:0  ZZ:Z:mus.sup  NM:i:0  MD:Z:50  ZZ:Z:cas.sup  CO:Z:endOfLine | tr ' ' '\n' | grep "ZZ:Z"
```

and if you want all back into a single line, just add `| tr '\n' ' '` at the end for converting back `\n` into spaces.

Of course you could also replace `grep` with `sed` in this solution.

Comment: would appreciate if someone could come up with sed solution so to avoid piping, and as for future reference...
I was hoping to see a sed solution that may implement the use of word boundaries (\b). therefore allowing to fetch everything that is after ZZ:Z, but before the next right boundary. something such as: 
\bZZ:Z:.*\b  
but I couldn't figure the correct sed syntax...